# Getting error in compiling bridging header swift

Tags: xcode, swift, alamofire, fmdb, bridging-header

This project was running successfully in xcode version which is before 7.3.1
But now I have installed xcode 7.3.1 and a lot of errors I am getting and few of them are related to bridging header that it can not find it. Can anyone figure out what's wrong here?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as i see from photo it seems FMDB files are missing also for easing your integration you should try Carthage or cocoapods.

Answer (score 0):

No need for Pods or carthage. This is the error because of missing files. Red color suggests for missing files in Xcode.

So just you have to delete and copy/import both files again,Surely works.
and at last don't forget to clean project-> cmd + k (Xcode-Product-Clean)
Just follow the steps below:

**Just go to Finder with Project Directory**

-> Delete all FMDB files

-> Delete .sqlite file

-> Copy/import again both files.

-> If it asks for "Bridging header file" then simple add it.

Xcode-Product-Clean and Build (Cmd+B) -> Run (Cmd+R).

Any query, check out below link or happy to help you:

http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/use-sqlite-database-swift